# Mysqldump multiple tables with where clauses in single transaction

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select, mysqldump, where

Suppose, we have 2 tables: **t1,t2** in database **db**:
Expected the below code to dump tables based on conditions specified in the `where` clauses:

```
mysqldump --login-path=login_path \
    --single-transaction db t1 \
    --where="user_id>200" , t2 --where="id>200" > /tmp/users_data.sql
```

However the following error is popped:

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM t1
>   WHERE id>200 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (1054)

How to dump multiple tables with `where` clauses  using `mysqldump` correctly? If it's not possible, is there a workaround?

Comment: IMO it's a wrong job for mysqldump

Comment: the goal is to dump multiple related tables atomically

Comment: Check mustaccio’s answer. His solution #1 will work for you

Answer (score 1):

MySQL dump has only a single `where` clause which makes the use hard in two tables like you do.

One way would be in t1, create a generated column called `id` that is effectively `user_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE t1
ADD id UNSIGNED INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (user_id),
ADD INDEX id_key ( id)
```

Adjust type to match the type of `user_id`.

ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:-

Dump Table data Using `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement which writes the selected rows to a file & Restore into table using `LOAD DATA` statement.

Eg.

- Take backup of table from Backup Server using

  ```
  SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM DB.T1 WHERE user_id>200;
  ```
- Create Same T1 table on Restore Server Using

  ```
  CREATE TABLE T1 (...)
  ```
- Copy files from Backup Server to Restore Server ( Using the `scp` command on Linux)
- Restore Data in Table using

  ```
  LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/result.txt' INTO TABLE DB.T1;
  ```

Solution 2:-

Need to prepare shell script which will pass value to where option in `mysqldump` command for each table.

Comment: I like your SELECT INTO FILE solution. You can wrap two of them into a transaction and achieve what OP asks for.

Comment: Solution 2 will not work correctly because two mysqldumps would be two transactions

Comment: @akuzminsky the following error pops `Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement` when running the `select * into file...` and have no permission to `/var/lib/mysql-files/`

Comment: That’s a separate problem. You may want to create another question for that

Comment: @user1264304 Check parameter value of --secure-file-priv & assign that path into SELECT * into /PATH/filename & if you have linux based server check privileges of that path.